# ¿Cómo actualizar una vista del listview?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, array, android-listview

Tengo un arrayList el cual almacena los datos presentados en el Listview, mi problema es que al inicio de la actividad, entra al mensaje sin poder actualizar o mostrar los datos, si llama a la actividad más de dos veces se muestran los datos.

```
adapter = new MyAdapterSec(this, misCasosArrayListsec);


listView.setAdapter(adapter);


count_item = listView.getAdapter().getCount();

        if(count_item > 0) {
            mensaje_default.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            actualizar();
            mensaje_default.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Solo tienes que llamar [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) de tu Adapter.

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Otra opciòn es llamar [invalidateViews()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView#invalidateViews()) si quieres que las vistas se actualicen dentro de tu `ListView`:

```
listview.invalidateViews();
```

Comment: Normalmente dode puedo mandar llamar esas instrucciones